# how to I get user-Agent from a server log data using java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, split

I have such raw data as string:

```
0.0.0.243   01/Jan/2011:01:01:01 +0000  GET /xxxxxx-design?CMP=XXX-xxxx_XxXXxxX&part=0000 HTTP/1.1  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36" 0.008 0.007 . xx-xxx-xx-xxx-xx xxxxx
```

How can I get the user-Agent part:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36`

By using regular expression in JAVA

Comment: I don't think you can. User agent has no formal format and can consist of several concatenated values of different structure, length and  order

Comment: That only has one double-quote (`"`) in it.  Are you sure it's complete?  If that's consistent, you'd want `\sHTTP/[0-9.]+\s+([^"]+)` as your regex, which gives you the UA in `$1`, but I don't know Java well enough to give you code.